# Why does it give me an error in class parsing?

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm trying to parse the dollar rate from the site https://yandex.ru/. He did everything according to all the canons. Tell me what's wrong?

```
response = requests.get('https://yandex.ru')
body = html.fromstring(response.text)
dollar = body.xpath('//span[@class="inline-stocks__value_inner"]/text()')[0]
```

The error is the following:

```
dollar = body.xpath('//span[@class="inline-stocks__value_inner"]/text()')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: probably dollar is an empty list, so 0 is out of range. do `print(dollar)` and see what it contains

Comment: There's no `class="inline-stocks__value_inner"` in the HTML. It's added by JavaScript.